# Place pause between actions in tkinter

Tags: tkinter, sleep, poker

I am writing some code to play poker, and when the cards are dealt I would like a small pause between each card being shown. I have seen other answers which suggest using sleep or after, however I find that these pause the program but then show the cards simultaneously. I would like a pause between each card. This is my code as slimmed down as I can put it.

```py
from tkinter import *
import time

x = Tk()
x.state('zoomed')

def lay():
    card1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2) # here I want to put a short pause
    #time.sleep(1)  or x.after(1000)
    card2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2)    

card1 = 'ad.gif'
card2 = '4c.gif'

a = PhotoImage(file='ad.gif')
card2 = Label(x, image=a)
b = PhotoImage(file='4c.gif')
card1 = Label(x, image=b)

Button(x, text='LAY CARDS', command=lay).place(relx=0.5, rely=0.5)

x.mainloop
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.after()` to show `card2` after one second:

```py
def lay():
    card1.place(relx=0.2, rely=0.2)
    # show card2 one second later
    x.after(1000, lambda: card2.place(relx=0.4, rely=0.2))
```

Comment: Perfect, that's just what I was looking for. Thanks also to Cool Cloud, whose solution also works.